# How to import Nodes and Node Location data using Feeds module?

Tags: 7, nodes, feeds, location

I would like to use Feeds to import Node Location data together with Nodes themselves.

Each node of a selected content type is or is not assigned to a location.

How to do this ?

Comment: Consider refining your question and don't ask yes/no questions. There is always a way (write a lot of code), so a simple and correct answer would be: "Yes".

Comment: I did something similar.  Here's my answer to this where I used SQL and feeds: [Drupal 7 content import](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/16131/2531)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, definitely go with feeds except I would go with [location module](http://drupal.org/project/location) instead of geofield personally as it has direct support from the [location_feeds module](http://drupal.org/project/location_feeds) for mapping in all the relevant details. Its possible that you may need to do two seperate feeds (one for importing the node information and one for the location information) but you can make sure they "come together" by using the same GUID field from your feed on each one. The easiest way is to try :) Set up a dummy file first with only 10 imports.

Comment: I would like to import with two separate feeds as you mentioned above. Can you please explain in more detail "make sure they "come together" by using the same GUID field from your feed on each one". I tried to run two separate feeds and they create separate nodes although I use matching GUID field values in both.

Comment: I think I may have pulled that bit from memory with using Drupal 6 as it appears that http://drupal.org/project/feeds_node_multisource never made it to Drupal 7 (although Im sure I have done it through GUID in d7, I will see if I can dig up where). Do you have to do it with 2 seperate feeds? The location_feeds mapper should work anyway.

Comment: Thank you, I managed to use one source file for this data load.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Geofield module](http://drupal.org/project/geofield) for mapping of location data when pulling in your feed. There's a page on the Drupal community documentation about [mapping using Open Layers and Feeds](http://drupal.org/node/1365574) that may help you.